# how to highlight invalid jquery input by creating border red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i highlight error in input jquery validation??

please help me

```
$(function () {
    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            month: "required",
            day: "required",
            year: "required",
            gender: "required",
            email: "required",
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 11
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                equalTo: "#confirm-password"
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Didnt you find our answers useful? :(

Answer (score 2):

this two element put in jquery validate to highlight error

```
errorElement: "div",
        errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideDown',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            element.addClass("edited");
           element.parents(".form-control-focus   > div").append(error);
            error.insertAfter(element);
            element.parents(".form-group  > div").append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (e)
        {
            $(e).closest(".input-group ").parent().removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-error"), $(e).closest(".help-block").remove();
            $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-error"), $(e).closest(".help-block").remove();
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit CSS - not Javascript. Input field with error will get "error" class attached to itself.

Next time - use HTML inspector to see what classes are added/changed ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this by adding CSS styles.

If you look the jQuery validation behavior, **error** class will be added to your input elements.

So simple do this

```
.error {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/780/)

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) of the jQuery validate plugin explains how to do it:

> **errorClass** (default: `"error"`)
>
> Type: String
>
> Use this class to
>   create error labels, to look for existing error labels and to add it
>   to invalid elements.
>
> Example: Sets the error class to “invalid”.
>
> ```
> $(".selector").validate({
>   errorClass: "invalid"
> });
> ```

Also the valid one:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  validClass: "success"
});
```

You will of course need to add these two classes to your css.

```
.invalid { border: 1px solid red }
```

Answer (score -1):

Something else to think about is native browser functionality with HTML 5.  You can use the required attribute and other validation attributes based on input type as well.